# Javascript getting XML node names loop does not stop

Tags: javascript, xml, loops, parsing

I have a XML-File which looks like this:

```
<ROWSET>
   <ROW>
      <option1> lala </option1>
      ...
      <option39> lolo </option39>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <option1> baba </option1>
      ...
      <option39> bobo </option39>
   </ROW>
   ...
</ROWSET>
```

All together the file contains 840 ROWs. I now have a some javascript code that gets me the node names ("option1", "option2", ..., "option39") and prints them via console.log.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
var reihen = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ROW");

for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < (eigenschaften * 2); j++) {
        var reihe = reihen[i].childNodes[j];

        if (reihe.nodeType === 1)
            console.log(reihe.nodeName + j + " " + i);
        }
    }
```

eigenschaften = 39 (amount of the nodes per ROW).

Unfortunately it doesn't stop after giving me the 39 node names; it just continues until my browser crashes. How do I end the loop? For some reason it doesn't stop after i > 1, it just continues with i = 0.

So after it gave me "option39" it instantly starts over with "option1".

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: why are you multiplying by 2?

Comment: If I don't, it gets only half of the options for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like there is something else in the code we do not see that is causing the problem. But seems like to me you should just reference the lengths and use that in the loops in stead of variables with the numbers.

```js
var xmlStr = `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
   <ROW>
      <option1> lala1 </option1>
      <option2> lala2 </option2>
      <option3> lala3 </option3>
      <option4> lala4 </option4>
      <option5> lala5 </option5>
      <option39> lolo </option39>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <option1> baba1 </option1>
      <option2> baba2 </option2>
      <option3> baba3 </option3>
      <option4> baba4 </option4>
      <option5> baba5 </option5>
      <option39> bobo </option39>
   </ROW>
</ROWSET>`


var xmlDoc = new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml")


//var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
var reihen = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ROW");
for (var i = 0; i < reihen.length; i++) {
  var rowChildren = reihen[i].childNodes
  for (var j = 0; j < rowChildren.length; j++) {
    var reihe = rowChildren[j];
    if (reihe.nodeType === 1)
      console.log(reihe.nodeName + ' ' + j + " " + i);
  }
}
```

just reading the first row

```js
var xmlStr = `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
   <ROW>
      <option1> lala1 </option1>
      <option2> lala2 </option2>
      <option3> lala3 </option3>
      <option4> lala4 </option4>
      <option5> lala5 </option5>
      <option39> lolo </option39>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <option1> baba1 </option1>
      <option2> baba2 </option2>
      <option3> baba3 </option3>
      <option4> baba4 </option4>
      <option5> baba5 </option5>
      <option39> bobo </option39>
   </ROW>
</ROWSET>`


var xmlDoc = new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml")


//var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
var reihen = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ROW");
var rowChildren = reihen[0].childNodes
for (var j = 0; j < rowChildren.length; j++) {
  var reihe = rowChildren[j];
  if (reihe.nodeType === 1)
    console.log(reihe.nodeName + ' ' + j);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So with your modification it still gives all the options as often as rows exists. How can I get every option just once?

Comment: You just want the option names? Thought you were trying to loop over all the rows.... Than just reference the first row....

Comment: that's what I tried to do with the first for-loop but it didn't work...

Comment: For some reason this does not work... may it have something to do with me using `var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML` instead of `var xmlDoc = new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml")`?

Comment: Okay. But still I can't get it to stop after the first row... I now it should but it doesn't

Comment: It gives me the first row, then says `TypeError: xml is undefined` and starts again

Comment: ookay. I moved it to somewhere else in my code and now it is working. Now I just have to figure out how to move it back without it crashing again... Thank you very much man! :)